# Cannot import R from my application on eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello i can't import the R with the layouts resources from my app this is the code i followed exactly how i find it but eclipse won't run the application

```
package menu.packg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

import menu.packg.R;


public class Menuactivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to import your `R.java` file at all.  It is automatically generated (if you have valid XML) and taken care of for you.

Comment: But eclipse won't run the app without the R file, the XML is totally valid because i've created using the eclipse.

Comment: Creating the XML within Eclipse doesn't make it valid.  If it isn't generating an R file for you automatically, then something is wrong with your XML files, likely just a small syntax error.  Try cleaning your project as well.

Comment: I' ve checked and solve all the problems on my XML and still nothing.

Comment: Make sure now that the `R.java` file is not being imported anywhere in your code.  When the file isn't being generated, sometimes Eclipse will auto-import the first `R.java` file it finds to try and "correct" the syntax errors.  This will mask the errors in Eclipse.  Or is the file still not being generated at all for you?

Comment: The file is generated by eclipse, the problem is the importing eclipse is not importing the file.

Answer (score 2):

R is automatically generated. But still if you want to create R.java in your gen directory then try to use this.

```
-> Right click on the Respective Project Folder in eclipse
-> Click Properties, then select Java Build Path, then select source
-> Now select Add Folder at right side of that window,
-> Select on gen folder -> then select Ok, again Ok.
```

Now you will get that respective gen package of the Project. Now try to clean the project.

Hope it will help you. I have done like this and it helps me a lot.

Enjoy.

:)

Comment: I am trying this but it's unaviable to select the gen folder.

Comment: @hindura : Which Eclipse version you are using ?

Comment: I am also using Indigo but on Windows. Dont have idea about Ubuntu. But as per i know you must have that option in that Eclipse. Please check it carefully.

Comment: The file is generated the problem still persisting on the R that is not imported.

Comment: I think you have imported the project tht is not from your workspace. Is it true then let me know. I have another solution of it.

Comment: i think you got solution. if not then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check all of your XML,
2. Project -> Clean,
3. Right click -> Fix Project Properties,
4. Repeat.
5. Maybe try restarting Eclipse

My panic list for R generation problems

Comment: @AlexLockwood: You can't code iOS in Visual Studio.  Checkmate.

Comment: @Will: hahaha, then the Windows phone it is!

Answer (score 1):

Also, from my experience sometimes if you have a problem with your layout, the build will NOT complete and hence `R.java` will not be generated properly.

Are you sure your layouts don't have errors?